# How to use `matches()` with a database function?

Tags: arel

I had an ActiveRecord scope like this:

```
scope :matching, ->(query) {
  where Post.arel_table[:title].matches "%#{query}%"
}
```

This worked fine.  I then changed it to ignore extra whitespace in the `title`:

```
scope :matching, ->(query) {
  where "regexp_replace(title, '\\s+', ' ', 'g') ILIKE ?", "%#{query}%"
}
```

This works but I have had to drop down from `matches()` (at the Ruby level) to `ILIKE` (at the SQL level).

Is it possible to use `regexp_replace(...)` with `matches()`?  For example:

```
scope :matching, ->(query) {
  where handwaving("regexp_replace(title, '\\s+', ' ', 'g')").matches "%#{query}%"
}
```

(I tried to use an `Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction` but couldn't get it to work.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can construct the `Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction` as follows:

```
condition = Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new(
   'regex_replace', 
   [Post.arel_attribute(:title),
    Arel.sql("'\\s+'"),
    Arel.sql("' '"), 
    Arel.sql("'g'")]
).matches("%#{query}%")
```

Then

```
scope :matching, ->(query) {
  # above condition code
  where(condition)
}
```

This will result in the following (`query = 'testing'`)

```
SELECT 
  posts.*
FROM 
  posts
WHERE 
  regex_replace(posts.title, '\\s+',' ','g') ILIKE '%testing%'
```

Comment: Thank you!  I was missing the `Arel.sql()` wrappers and getting type mismatches.